# What is the attribute you need to specify for kafka Log start offset metric?

Tags: linux, kafka

I have an environment where logstash (v6.2.3) is connecting kafka_2.11 cluster (v.1.1.0) using kafka input.

What I want to achieve is fetch consumer offset information using *kafka-consumer-group.sh* . However, I end up with below error.

```
[ywatanabe@centos74 kafka]$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group logstash --describe
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to null
```

So I am now diagnosing this problem first by directly accessing to metric information using *jmxterm*. Problem is , I do not understand what you need to specify for the attribue.

```
$>info -b kafka.log:name=LogStartOffset,partition=2,topic=my-first-topic-1,type=Log
#mbean = kafka.log:name=LogStartOffset,partition=2,topic=my-first-topic-1,type=Log
#class name = com.yammer.metrics.reporting.JmxReporter$Gauge
# attributes
  %0   - Value (java.lang.Object, r)
# operations
  %0   - javax.management.ObjectName objectName()
#there's no notifications
```

What do you exactly need to specify for **Value** ?